# How to pass the name of the selected table via Google Picker to the function in code.gs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

From a file picker.html pass the value of the name variable to the file code.gs

picker.html  :

```
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
    if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) { 
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var name = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = name; 
    } 
    else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        google.script.host.close();
    }
  }
```